# How to delete symlinks with phing?

Tags: php, windows, cross-platform, symlink, phing

How can I delete symlinks with phing so it will work on Windows too?

Creating a symlink is easy and works cross-plattform:

```
<symlink 
    target="${sharedPath}zend-framework/ZendFramework-${version.zf}/library/Zend/" 
    link="library/Zend" />
```

But neither

```
<delete dir="symlinked folder" />
```

nor

```
<delete file="symlinked folder" />
```

will remove the symlink.

How to do this?

---

Additional information:

- I'm running phing 2.4.10
- Phing actually outputs [delete] path to deleted file/folder, but the symlink is still there afterwards. so there's no error message and no obvious failure.

Comment: Do you know what kind of failure is occurring?  A quick look through the source and it appears there should be support for links.  **DeleteTask.php** operates on _PhingFile_ instances which have support for links.  It looks like there's a number of places Phing is trying to indicate what the failure may be so I wonder if that's not being captured here.  At the very least you could debug the code as it flows through those files (DeleteTask.php & PhingFile.php).

Comment: What version of Phing are you running?

Comment: Are you adverse to editing the code inside of Phing?  Looks like it should be getting into this function in FileSystem.php, maybe remove the @ in front of **unlink** and see if something pops up
    `function unlink($file) {
        global $php_errormsg;
        if (false === @unlink($file)) {
            $msg = "FileSystem::unlink() FAILED. Cannot unlink '$file'. $php_errormsg";
            throw new IOException($msg);
        }   
    }`

Comment: Using the following snippet to reproduce:

`<target name="test">
  <mkdir dir="temp"/>
  <symlink target="build.xml" link="test.xml"/>
  <symlink target="temp" link="linkdir"/>
  <delete file="test.xml"/>
  <delete file="linkdir"/>
 </target>`

Runs fine on Linux, errors out on the delete linkdir on Windows. Not really sure how to fix it (I maintain Phing).

Comment: I'll be getting back to you guys when I'm on that project again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because symlink which you are creating on Windows, is not a real symlink, but rather .LNK file. 
So, it is a directory, but not a link. Thus, deleting as a file wont work.

So you can neither use some windows special exec to create actual symlink (but existence of those depends of version and / or privileges - look for example at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768 for details on junction), or use some scary method for testing if given file is in fact a .LNK file (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-link.php#91249)